# EOF character not found

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am web-scraping pdfs with Python, and I'm running into a problem with 1.6% of the files I'm analyzing. The error being thrown is "EOF marker not found." However, I have looked at the byte content of the file in question, and the '%%EOF' is right there at the end of the file followed by a new-line character, meaning it's well within 1024 bytes of the end of the file.

I have tried using a function that someone on a similar post wrote, but I think it's outdated and it doesn't work. I have also tried appending an EOF character to the end of every file, but that also didn't work. I may have done it wrong, but I don't think it would work anyway.

If it helps, I'm using the get requests from the requests module, and PyPDF2 to read a memory PDF that I'm using ByteIO for.

Edit: here's the link to one of the PDFs that's giving me an issue.
https://www.burlingtonvt.gov/sites/default/files/08.27.2022.pdf

Comment: You should maybe use a package that is able to dynamically repair a PDF while processing it. Try [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: Consider sharing an example PDF here for which that occurs.

Comment: Although that PDF ends in `%%EOF` , it's got an incorrect index, which makes it unreadable to many tools.  Starts to go south  at line 4 of the `xref` (near the bottom) which has `0000000009 00000 n` for the first object (byte offset 9). However the first object in the PDF is at byte offset 10.

Comment: @dwarring *"Starts to go south at line 4"* - I checked some more entries, _all_ offsets in the xref table appear to be off by 1, starting at object 1. @ Zayenus, that PDF simply has a completely broken cross reference table. The error message indeed is a bit misleading, though...

Comment: @mkl So do I just need to throw those PDFs out? I'm worried about checking different sets of PDFs and having more of them be broken to the point where my data is too far off. Is there any way to fix them?

Comment: @Zayenus *"So do I just need to throw those PDFs out?"* - Not necessarily. Some PDF processors can repair such issues (it's merely an off-by-1 in the example document, and in the harmless direction). Unfortunately I don't know which Python libs are able to do so as I'm mostly into Java.

Comment: @mkl I'm actually better with Java, I only chose Python because I was trying to quickly write a script and because I'm not familiar with any web scraping or PDF modules in Java. I know they exist I've just never used them. Do you some good ones off the top of your head? If so I'll switch to Java and try to fix the PDFs.

Comment: I happen to know some Java PDF libraries, in the open source context in particular iText and PDFBox, and I would assume that both will load the example PDF. (I just tried with the current iText 7 version and it worked.)

Comment: I'm revisiting this after coming across another similar PDF produced by `Microsoft: Print to PDF`. The upshot is that every object begins with a blank and carries right through to the byte before the next indirect object. Rereading PDF ISO-32000 section 7.5.5  doesn't rule it out. I'm  now thinking it's 'odd' rather than 'broken'.